# Convert a state-space model with exogenous input to one without

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, state-space-models, dlm, linear-dynamical-system

I have a state space model of the form

\begin{align}
x_{t+1} &= Ax_t + Bu_t + w_t\\
y_t &= Cx_t + Du_t + v_t
\end{align}
where $u$ is the exogenous input. Also, $ w_t \sim N(0, Q)$ and $v_t \sim N(0, R)$. My goal is to estimate the parameters $A, B, C, D, Q$ and $R$ together with the hidden state $x$.

The `R` package `dlm` doesn't allow exogenous input. So I thought of first fitting this model
\begin{align}
x_{t+1} &= Ax_t + \varepsilon_t\\
y_t &= Cx_t + \eta_t
\end{align}
and then fitting the covariates
\begin{align}
\varepsilon_t &= Bu_t + w_t\\
\eta_t &= Du_t + v_t
\end{align}
But I'm afraid this trick might be too simplistic. Is there a theoretical reason why this is right or wrong?

Comment: Hi: if exogenous input is known and so are $B$ and $D$, can you just subtract them from both sides of the two equations, and then you'll have a new state space model without exogenous input ? I could be missing something obvious here.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The parameters $A, B, C, D$ as well as the variance $Q$ of $w$ and $R$ of $v$ are all unknown and must be estimated. Only $u$ is known. I plan to use the EM algorithm as presented in [this paper](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/tr-96-2.pdf) which I believe is how `dlm` is implemented. But the paper and `dlm`  both don't include exogenous inputs.

Comment: Oh Okay. In the more standard kalman filter-state space model framework, A and C are known. You've got a different problem there for sure that I'm not familiar with. Note though that dlm package in R does not solve the problem in the paper you refer to. The dlm package in R assumes A and C are known and it estimates state x_t and the respective covariance matrices  using a bayesian framework or harvey's classical  structural framework ( maybe both. I forget ).  There are other KF packages in R that may deal with the problem that you're considering. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I can write the code from the paper myself, but still I want to know if I can use this trick.

Comment: I've worked with the Kalman filter but not with those matrices unknown so I can't say and hopefully someone else can answer. If not, maybe ask the authors of the paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to move the coefficient of the exogenous process into the state, make it constant, and treat $u_t$ as a (known) time-varying coefficient.

As a simple example, assume both the state and the observation are one-dimensional:

\begin{align}
x_t &= a x_{t-1} + b u_{t-1} + w_t\\
y_t &= c x_t + d u_{t} + v_t
\end{align}

Define the new state vector $z_t=[x_t, b_t, d_t]^T$, and the corresponding state equations:

\begin{align}
x_t &= a x_{t-1} + u_{t-1}b_{t-1} + w_t\\
b_t &= b_{t-1}\\
d_t &= d_{t-1}
\end{align}

The measurement equation becomes:
$$y_t = [c, 0, u_t]z_t + v_t$$

This is then a standard linear state-space model with 3 state variables, and some time-varying coefficients.

This is actually the methodology used by `dlm::dlmModReg` to define a regression model. `dlm` does indeed allow for fitting unknown parameters of linear Gaussian state space models (by MLE), and it allows for time-varying parameters as well (you will have to adjust the parameters `JGG` and `JFF` to have time-varying transition/observation matrices).

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. Apart from setting the parameters to time varying, I also have to set them to be partially fixed. I'll see how I can do that. Meanwhile, could you tell me why is my trick wrong?

Comment: @Drumy Could you expand on your trick? It looks like you first assume $\varepsilon_t$ is mean zero when fitting the first step, and then that its mean is $Bu_t$ in the second. This would bias the estimates of $A$, for example.

Comment: Ahh, I see! Thank you @ChrisHaug for clarifying. I had a hunch that the trick was too simplistic and should be wrong but couldn't pin-point it. Now I realize it's the assumptions behind.